# If we use SoundFlower to record the system's audio output, then we can't hear it at the same time?

Tags: audio, video-capture

[SoundFlower](http://code.google.com/p/soundflower/) can let us play the system's audio to the SoundFlower 2 channel and record with this SoundFlower 2 channel, so QuickTime on Mac OS X Lion and record exactly what the system is playing for a game play.

And it works for 16 channels as well.

But is it true that while we can record the sound, we can't hear it?  So if we are playing a game and we are recording the video/sound, then we can't hear it.  I just wanted to set it up to record the ending credit and the song, but if it needs to be played without sound, then that's somewhat a problem too.

Comment: You might want a new screen record in general. Apps like ScreenFlow take up FAR less resources while recording, resulting in far smoother gameplay. Plus they have application sound capturing ability built in, without the need for sound flower and sound flower bed.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

No. You can still hear the sound by creating a new audio device in Audio MIDI Setup. Go to the SoundFlower menu and click "Audio Setup". Audio MIDI Setup should popup up. Create a new multi-output device (click the + in the bottom left hand corner). Then set the settings as pictured below:
[image: Audio MIDI Setup]
This will allow you to capture the system sound *and* still hear it through your speakers/headphones.

Comment: Only problem is this disables the volume control for the mac (both menu item and keyboard)! :(

Comment: Thanks so much for this information. I'd tried everything else and nothing had worked, but finally!!! I note that someone had said that it disabled the volume control on both the menu and the keyboard, but that doesn't occur for me. I think this was about the last thing I needed to do to make my Mac more Windows-like so my appreciation for that!!!

Comment: This works, I can record audio (input = soundflower) and hear it in the speakers. The problem is, there is an echo: it sounds like the sound is played twice with a short delay. It's also how it's recorded. Any idea why?

Comment: If you don't have a Soundflower menu, you can bring this up by clicking `/Applications/Utilities/Audio MIDI Setup`.

Answer (score 16):

When you install Soundflower, you should also have an application named "Soundflowerbed" located in `Applications > Soundflower`.

[image: Soundflowerbed App Icon]

When you launch it it opens only into your menu bar.

[image]

Clicking it reveals a menu that is used to route the output to another device of your choosing.

[image]

Selecting Built-In Output, or the output device of your choosing, will allow you to monitor the audio Soundflower is capturing.

Comment: I get a horrendous feedback loop when I do this on my MBP Retina, even though my input is set to the microphone. Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: Try wearing headphones?

Comment: Try creating an aggregate audio output as described in previous answer and select the "Drift correction". It will keep the two audio output in sync.

Comment: I don't see this in my app folder? ‍♂️

Comment: Soundflower has changed in the 7 years since this answer was posted. There may be better tools for you to use by now.

Answer (score 1):

I own a MacBook with Retina Display.  The process is a little difficult, but you do need to follow the 2 other instructions listed here, about Soundflowerbed & Audio MIDI Setup.

The 3rd & Final Step for me was to go to SYSTEM PREFERENCES > SOUND ...

1) Under the OUTPUT tab, select "Multi-Output Device"

2) Under the INPUT tab, select "Soundflower 2ch"

Now I can record audio/video while using my headphones; although the volume cannot be controlled via the computer & when recording sound the volume is a bit low.  But once I revert back the Input/Output options under SYSTEM PREFERENCES > SOUND, the audio is back to its proper volume.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll also need Jack http://jackaudio.org.

Do the following mappings: as mentioned create a Multidevice with the Soundflower 16 and the built in audio.

Next select soundflower 16 as the device for audio output in System Preferences. (Sys. Audio is Routed to Soundflouwer Input 1/2)

If you wana here your Game play select Bultin Output in Soundflower Menu (the one below the 16Channel green/yellow)

Now start Jack (it take a few moments) when its running creat the following routing Soundflower Input 1 to Soundflower Output 1 + 3 and Input 2 to Output 2 + 4.

In your Recording Software (i recommend Audacity for Audio) you can now select Soundflower 3/4 as Input.