# Soundflower difficulties

Tags: audio, quicktime, soundflower

I recently downloaded Soundflower so I could record some audio with the imagery I can already record through QuickTime. The thing is, once I've set Soundflower up I can't hear anything on my computer! I already found an answer to this problem in an old forum on this site and did as one of the answers suggested, but I *still* can't hear anything it's driving me up the wall!

Can someone please help me out?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! It would help if you could edit the things you've already tried into your post, so people don't propose the same things again. Adding a screenshot of the Soundflower preferences might help as well.

Comment: Did you try [selecting an output from Soundflowerbed or adding a multi-output device](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/50904)?

Comment: If you are still searching for an answer, see [this answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/146695/65995) on a similar question.

Answer (score 1):

I was having audio issues with soundflower causing digital noise once I got it working.  This work around may help your issue too.

A friend suggested an idea that he had been shown. Setup soundflower as a midi simultaneously with your regular output. Therefore instead of routing through soundflower for your output (which seems to cause the issue), it routes each as their own output. So far seems to be working on my recording meters without the overdrive static. [Here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/50904/if-we-use-soundflower-to-record-the-systems-audio-output-then-we-cant-hear-it) is the how to on this.

Also, if you are looking for more control I found software from [Prosoft](http://www.prosofteng.com/products/) that allows for audio adjustment using hear or individual app volume control through hear or soundbunny.