# How can I create video loopback devices on OS X? Is there a Mac equivalent of v4l2loopback?

Tags: video, driver, streaming

In Linux, I can use `v4l2loopback` to create virtual devices and use them as video inputs/outputs. Is there an equivalent toolset for OS X? How does one create multiple streams of videos on MacBook?

Answer (score 1):

#### Audio Loopback

For audio loopback devices I'm familiar with [Soundflower](https://rogueamoeba.com/freebies/soundflower/). From the looks of it there appears to be an alternative called Loopback which is a paid-for application.

- [Soundflower GitHub Repo](https://github.com/mattingalls/Soundflower)
- [Loopback](https://rogueamoeba.com/loopback/(

**NOTE:** Soundflower is available as a binary build from the Github repo.

#### Video Loopback

For video loopback devices you have a couple of options. Searching led me to this page on Stackoverflow - [gstreamer create virtual device on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44287784/gstreamer-create-virtual-device-on-osx)
.

That Q&A mentions that you can use [`gstreamer`](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/osx/1.12.0/) which provides a DMG file to use on OSX.

```
$ ./gst-launch-1.0 -v videotestsrc pattern=snow ! video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720 ! osxvideosink
```

There's also another option which mentions the framework [CoreMediaIO](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/CoreMediaIO/Introduction/Intro.html). As part of that framework is sample code and documentation which covers creating a custom solution to construct a loopback device for video.

#### References

- [Rogue Amoeba info page about Soundflower](https://rogueamoeba.com/freebies/soundflower/)
- [Record your computer's screen with audio on a Mac](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/record-your-computers-screen-with-audio-on-a-mac/)
- [How can I send my computer's audio to multiple outputs?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/54675/how-can-i-send-my-computers-audio-to-multiple-outputs)
- [If we use SoundFlower to record the system's audio output, then we can't hear it at the same time?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/50904/if-we-use-soundflower-to-record-the-systems-audio-output-then-we-cant-hear-it)

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the video part of your answer? Everything you linked to is very vague. (And the command you pasted, in and of itself, does not create a video loopback device).